# Kth Smallest Element in a BST

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, binary-search

I was trying a leetcode problem - [find the kth smallest element in a binary search tree](https://leetcode.com/problems/kth-smallest-element-in-a-bst/). I think the solution which I wrote is correct, but it is not passing all the test cases, and I am not able figure out where I am going wrong. Below is my solution:

```
class Solution(object):
    def kthSmallest(self, root, k, array=[]):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :type k: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        if root.left:
            return self.kthSmallest(root.left, k, array)
        array.append(root.val)
        if len(array) == k:
            return array[-1]
        if root.right:
            return self.kthSmallest(root.right, k, array)
```

Could anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Using a list literal as a default argument (`array=[]`) is a common gotcha. The array is created once when the function is defined, then the same array reference is used for each function call where `array` is not passed explicitly. Could have something to do with it.

Comment: I don't think so, since I ran few inputs using a visual editor [link](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit), and it was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

> Kth Smallest Element in a BST

Here's an algorithm to solve the problem:

1. Write a helper method that returns a BST node.
2. In the helper method, traverse the BST nodes in-order, decrementing k along the way.
3. When k reaches 1, return the current BST node to the original method.
4. The original method should then return the value within this node.

Geeks for Geeks has more information on [The Kth Smallest Element in a BST problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-k-th-smallest-element-in-bst-order-statistics-in-bst/).